# sometime get IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState after checked inFinishing

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

Had this before and resolved by checking activity isFinishing or is the onSaveInstanceState has been already called.

But sometime it still happen after it passed the check. It is just a list, and clicking on the item it will open another fragment to show details.

In the activity's handler the isFinishing() and whether the onSaveInstanceState has been called are checked and is fine, but the ft.commit() still causes IllegalStateException.

How could it happen since the list is still on display? What else could be used for preventing it?

again, in most of the time it is working fine but seeing reported crashes at this line sometime.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1832)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1850)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:643)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:603)
   at com.zeta.MainActivity.showMessageDetailsFragment(MainActivity.java:4522)
   at com.zeta.messagelist.ListFragment.onListItemClick(ListFragment.java:1945)
   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:60)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3073)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3910)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)



 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mInSaveInstanceState = true;
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }


 private void showMessageDetailsFragment(MessageContext messageContext) {
    if ((!mInSaveInstanceState) && !isFinishing()) {                        
        MessageDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new MessageDetailsFragment(messageContext);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_holder, detailsFragment, "DETAILS_FRAGMENT");
        ft.addToBackStack("DETAILS_FRAGMENT");   
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.hold, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE,
                        R.anim.slide_left_in, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
        ft.show(detailsFragment);
        ft.commit();  //<=== java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: if you use replace, why are you using show after that? remove show and try

Comment: it was add() before, both add and replace having this exception SOMETIME.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
in place of
    ft.commit()

Comment: Thanks Pete! Dont want use commitAllowingStateLoss() without knowing why it happened.

Comment: Are you running anything in a background thread in the list click handler?